# Mule 3 HTML as property value

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a Mule 3 dw 1.0 application with a payload that is HTML which is produced by a parse template component (the mime type this produces is application/json). I want to use this unescaped HTML as a string value in a transform message component so I have something like:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
   "body": payload
}
```

however, I get an exception at this stage due to < character not being valid. I have tried converting the payload to a string, converting the payload to a string prior to this transform message, converting the JSON to an object then to a string. None of which worked.

Comment: Please show the complete error (all lines) and the XML of the flow you got so far. Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a new flow variable and importantly set its MIME type to text/html.